# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable Python 3

Tags: python

```
                if 'game' in release_object:
                game_object = release_object['game']
                game = {}
                if 'id' in game_object:
                    game['id'] = game_object['id']
```

Error comes from :

```
                if 'id' in game_object:
                    game['id'] = game_object['id']
```

Thank you very much for all your hard work, Every bit of help is greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You're apparently expecting `game_object` to be a dictionary, but it's actually an integer.

Comment: Added to comment from @JohnGordon if the game object is a list, use ' if gameobject.any() == 'id'.

Comment: @Saranns It can't be a list, because lists _are_ iterable, so he wouldn't have gotten that error message.